# Build Kannel SMS Gateway

Tags: sms-gateway, kannel

I apologize for this question but it is really important for me to know the answers.

After a lot of Googling I coudn't fine a proper answer from a kannel expert people.

I have setup kannel on my server and connect to 3 operators using SMPP. I am sending couple on hundreds of messages every day using my smstool.

`First Question:` Can Kannel act as SMPP server? In other words can my clients connect to my server with smpp connection?

`Second Question:` Depending on my server specs (CPU, Memory ,...) can Kannel handle millions of messages in a day time?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First question reply:

- Actual release of Kannel (1.4.4) does not support smpp server out of the box.
- You can add it through the smppbox ([more info](https://redmine.kannel.org/projects/smppbox)), it is not officially supported right now but you can try it at your own risk

Second question reply (assuming you're talking about delivering SMS MT messages):

- Kannel is very performant, with some basic hardware config (1 Gb RAM + 2 Cores) you can easily get 100 SMS per second (MT).
- But dont forget to tune up your configuration, the default config wont let you go so far
- Tuning may include using **sqlbox** instead of **smsbox**, multiple **sqlboxes** for load balancing and even multiple **bearerboxes** for even more load balancing stuff

Second question reply (assuming you're talking about receiving SMS MO messages):

- When receiving a message Kannel can send it to a third party application through http, execute a script or insert the message in a database.
- Depending on the response time of the third party application, Kannel can deliver messages with an acceptable throughput
- There's a lot of config items to be tuned to get more throughput and better resource management
- Using multiple boxes (**sqlbox** or **smsbox**) is a must to take full advantage of parallel processing and load balancing